# JavaScript function to convert JSON key-value object to query string

Tags: javascript, json, iterator, escaping, urlencode

I'm working on formatting a URL for the [Facebook Feed Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/). There's so many parameters though. I want to have a function for these dialogs, something like:

```
function generateDialogUrl(dialog, params) {
  base  = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/" + dialog + "?";
  tail = [];
  for (var p in params) {
    if (params.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      tail.push(p + "=" + escape(params[p]));
    }
  }
  return base + tail.join("&")
}
```

Oh wow... I think I just answered my own question. Is that right? Is `escape()` the correct function to use?

I'm stuck in the [Lovers source code](https://github.com/mattdipasquale/loversapp.com/blob/master/public/javascripts/lovers.js#L85).

UPDATE: Since, we're using jQuery, I rewrote the method using `jQuery.each`. I also replaced `escape()` with `encodeURIComponent()` as suggested by @galambalazs & @T.J. Crowder. Thanks, guys!

```
var generateDialogUrl = function (dialog, params) {
  base  = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/" + dialog + "?";
  tail = [];
  $.each(params, function(key, value) {
    tail.push(key + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value));
  })
  return base + tail.join("&");
}
```

It's working!

Comment: You may accept the answer if it solved your problem. :)

Comment: additionally, answers should not be placed in the question body; instead, the owner should answer it's own question and mark as accepted.

Comment: Just for information http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2011/05/04/jquery-create-url-query-string-from-jsonarray/ liks give another way..

Answer (score 7):

Better yet, use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) instead. See this [article](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/) comparing the two:

> The **escape()** method does not encode
>   the + character which is interpreted
>   as a space on the server side as well
>   as generated by forms with spaces in
>   their fields. Due to this shortcoming
>   and the fact that this function fails
>   to handle non-ASCII characters
>   correctly, you should **avoid** use of
>   escape() whenever possible. The **best
>   alternative** is usually
>   **encodeURIComponent()**.
>
> escape() will not encode: @*/+

Comment: +1 -- e.g., **no**, `escape` is not the right function to use, `encodeURIComponent` is. `escape` isn't for URL-encoding. It does something similar, but different.

Answer (score 2):

There is a jQuery method to accomplish this: [$.param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/). It would work like this:

```js
var generateDialogUrl = function (dialog, params) {
  base = 'http://www.facebook.com/dialog/' + dialog + '?';
  return base + $.param(params);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const createQueryParams = (param, prefix = '') => {
    let queryString = '';
    if (param.constructor === Object) {
        queryString = Object.keys(param).reduce((result, key) => {
            const obj = param[key];
            const queryParam = result ? `${result}&${prefix}` : prefix;
            if (obj.constructor === Object) {
                return `${queryParam}${createQueryParams(obj, `${key}.`)}`;
            } else if(obj.constructor === Array) {
                const qp= obj.map((item, index)=> {
                    if (item.constructor === Object || item.constructor === Array) {
                        const query = createQueryParams(item, `${key}[${index}].`);
                        return `${query}`;
                    } else {
                        return `${key}[${index}]=${item}`;
                    }
                }).reduce((res, cur) => {
                    return res ? `${res}&${cur}`: `${cur}`;
                }, '');

                return `${queryParam}${qp}`;
            } else {
                return `${queryParam}${key}=${obj}`;
            }
        }, '');
    } else if(param.constructor === Array) {
        queryString = param.reduce((res, cur) => `${res},${cur}`);
    } else {
        queryString = param;
    }

    return encodeURI(queryString);
};
```

Example:

```
createQueryParams({"Context":{"countryCode":"NO"},"Pagination":{"limit":10,"offset":1},"AdditionalField":[{"name":"Policy Number","value":"Pol123"},{"name":"Policy Version","value":"PV1"}]});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
convertJsonToQueryString: function (json, prefix) {
    //convertJsonToQueryString({ Name: 1, Children: [{ Age: 1 }, { Age: 2, Hoobbie: "eat" }], Info: { Age: 1, Height: 80 } })
    if (!json) return null;
    var str = "";
    for (var key in json) {
        var val = json[key];
        if (isJson(val)) {
            str += convertJsonToQueryString(val, ((prefix || key) + "."));
        } else if (typeof (val) == "object" && ("length" in val)) {
            for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
                //debugger
                str += convertJsonToQueryString(val[i], ((prefix || key) + "[" + i + "]."));
            }
        }
        else {
            str += "&" + ((prefix || "") + key) + "=" + val;
        }
    }
    return str ? str.substring(1) : str;
}

isJson = function (obj) {
    return typeof (obj) == "object" && Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).toLowerCase() == "[object object]" && !obj.length;
};
```

example:

```
convertJsonToQueryString({Name:1,Children:[{Age:1},{Age:2,Hoobbie:"eat"}],Info:{Age:1,Height:80}})
```

Result:

```
"Name=1Children[0].Age=1Children[1].Age=2&Children[1].Hoobbie=eatInfo.Age=1&Info.Height=80"
```